Obtain GIT_URL and GIT_BRANCH of a jenins multibranch pipeline without git fetch?
I have a jenkins multibranch pipeline, using a Jenkinsfile that performs the checkout locally:
pipeline {
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()   // Do not let the build job perform checkout.
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      // Perform local checkout using 'scm' variable.
      def vars = checkout(scm)

      // Get git url and branch from the returned scm vars.
      echo "GIT_URL = ${vars.GIT_URL}"
      echo "GIT_BRANCH = ${vars.GIT_BRANCH}"
    }
  }
}

I am using a very large git repository, and checkout can take some time, so I'd like to obtain GIT_URL and GIT_BRANCH before the checkout.
Accessing the scm global variable is actually a call to a function that will perform a git fetch operation, which can also take some time.
So is there any way to derive GIT_URL and GIT_BRANCH without actually calling a git checkout step or delegating to a git fetch operation?

Normally the url and branch would both be input parameters and not solely outputs. If you are not specifying them, then they would be the default values, and you could assume that instead of attempting to determine them.

The GIT_URL perhaps, but there can be multiple possible GIT_BRANCH values for a multibranch pipeline.

Actually the environment variable BRANCH_NAME will be set by jenkins, which can be used as a proxy for GIT_BRANCH, but the pipeline is used by multiple build jobs, so there may be multiple values for GIT_URL. I may need to set a property on the each multibranch pipeline for the GIT_URL, perhaps.
